# Mongodb insert an item in the array if item does not exist

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I want to insert an item in the array in mongodb collection  if item does not exist in the array.

e.g collection:

```json
{
    empId :100,
    empName: 'John',
    empTechnicalSkills: [ 
        { empid: 100, id: 1, value: 'mongodb' }, 
        { empid: 100, id: 2, value: '.net' }
    ]    
}
```

I want to update / push new skills if that skill does not exist and `empid` exist

e.g.

If I push `{ empid: 100, id:3 , value: 'sql server' }` it should add a new item in the array

If I push `{ empid: 100, id:1 , value: 'sql server' }` it should ignore as the `id=1` already exists

If I push `{ empid: 101, id:1 , value: 'sql server' }` it should create a new document and add one skill (like upsert)

```json
{
    empId: 101,
    empTechnicalSkills: [ 
        { empid: 101, id: 1, value: 'sql server' }
    ]
}
```

Could someone please help me to understand how to achieve this? I am using C#.

I tried different things aggregate pipeline with update, push the item by matching `{empId and empTechnicalSkills.id $ne provided id}`, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just perform a match or find before inserting? For the item you want to insert, try to find the document first that contains empId. You can then either do a second query to see if the item exists in `empTechnicalSkills` or you can just check in your code if it exists. Up to you where you'd rather do work. Then if it doesn't exist, run a mongo update with a push to add it to the array.

Comment: I am trying to do this in a single transaction with upsert, i know we should be able to solve this with multiple queries.


`_collection.UpdateOneAsync(
               FilterByEmpId(empId),
               Builders<Employee>.Update
                   .Pipeline(SaveEmployeeTechnicalSkill(skill)),
               new UpdateOptions
               {
                    IsUpsert = true
               }, cancellationToken);`